# Why can't a Meredith Graph be Hamiltonian?

Tags: graph-theory

I need to find out why [Meredith Graph](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8f/Meredith_graph_3COL.svg) is not Hamiltonian

Meredith Graph is so complex to analyze in this regard. Can anyone help me wih their expertise?

Comment: You might exploit the fact the peterson graph is not hamiltonian

Comment: How does Peterse Graph relate to Meredith? I observe all K3,4 graph in Meredith graph. Since K3,4 is not Hamiltonian, can I conclude that the graph obtained by onnecting 10 such K3,4 resulting Meredith Graphs is also not hamiltonian?

Answer (score 1):

The Meredith graph is roughly the Petersen graph where each vertex is replaced by
a bipartite 'cluster' of 7 vertices: 4 'connecting points' which are connected to the rest of the graph
and 3 'internal points' that have only edges inside the cluster.

Assume the Meredith graph has a Hamiltonian cycle.
If this cycle visits each cluster only once, it would give rise to a Hamiltonian cycle for the Petersen graph,
which is not possible.

So there must be at least one cluster that is visited twice.
You enter a cluster at one of the four connecting points, then you can visit at most one internal
point before you reach the next connecting point: then you already must leave the cluster.
This leaves one internal point in this cluster that cannot be on the Hamiltonian cycle.

Comment: Do we visit At most or at least ? I see it should be atleast . am I wrong? BTW we can always have a zig zag path to cover the entire vertices in the K3,4 and leave it. Then it comes down to the case of finding a Hamiltonian Cycle for Petersen graph which is not possible. Am I right? Please correct me if I am wrong or misunderstood you.

Comment: If we take a "zig zag" to cover all of a certain $K_{3,4}$ all its vertices are covered in
one visit. I have argued that there must be at least one $K_{3,4}$ that we have to visit twice.
In each $K_{3,4}$ that we visit twice we necessarily miss one 'internal' vertex.